# What is Outside JVM in Task manager UI in flink web ui?

Tags: apache-flink

[image]

While monitoring a streaming job on flink ui I encountered outside JVM .

What exactly it is and what is count column ?

Answer (score 1):

**Outsize JVM** refers to native memory used by flink TM. MemoryManager in flink TM will acquire native memory through `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` based on the congfiuration.

**Count Column** refers to number of buffers in the pool, decided by the number of calls to `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`.